# How to create table in PHP and Oracle

Tags: php, oracle

I am trying to create table in PHP and Oracle

```
 $create_table =" CREATE TABLE email_valid(
                                         eid int(11)   NOT NULL,
                                          email varchar2(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                                           password varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
                                            activation varchar2(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                                             status enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
                                              PRIMARY KEY (eid))";

$stid=oci_parse($conn,$create_table);
oci_execute($stid) or die(oci_error());
```

But the error occurred:

```
Warning: oci_execute() [function.oci-execute]: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis in C:\PORTAL\xampp\htdocs\email\create.php on line 15
```

I can't find out where the error is? Please help me.

Comment: Is the statement on line 15 really this create statement?

Comment: yah i checked that site before , but i cant justify the error where i have done mistake, could you please correct it.?

Comment: yes, the line number 15 is execute statement.

Comment: @Mahesh You don't specify lengths of INTs in ORACLE. `INT` is fine. Don't use `int(11)`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo , yes i removed the size for int , and the same error is getting

Comment: @Mahesh Perhaps it's complaining about your ENUM. Why not use `BOOLEAN`? Please check your syntax [here](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm).

Comment: @h2ooooooo   yah , i tried with boolean :         $create_table =" CREATE TABLE email_valid(                                         eid int NOT NULL,email varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,password varchar(255) NOT NULL,                                              activation varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
status BOOLEAN('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (eid))";    same error message , missing right paranthesis.

Comment: @Mahesh Don't use `BOOLEAN('0', '1')`. Just `BOOLEAN`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo , yes i used only BOOLEAN , same error message it is displaying

Comment: status BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Oracle does not have a sized `INT(11)` type, if you want to use size, you'll need to use `NUMERIC`.
- Oracle does not have `ENUM`, but in this case you can use a simple char with a `CHECK` constraint;

--

```
CREATE TABLE email_valid( 
  eid numeric(11)   NOT NULL,
  email varchar2(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  password varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
  activation varchar2(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  stats char(1) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL CHECK (stats IN ('0','1')),
  PRIMARY KEY (eid)
)
```

[A simple SQLfiddle test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a5b5e4/1).

Comment: "*Oracle does not have `ENUM`*" - this is the same conclusion that I came to, but [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/enum.html) threw me off. Why does Oracle have a docs page if it doesn't exist? Is it some sort of plugin? (I don't use Oracle myself).

Comment: @h2ooooooo I think you may have found [Oracle's ENUM documentation for MySQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/enum.html)...?

Comment: Ah of course - I just expected it to be Oracle documentation as I'd go to MySQL's site for their documentation, but considering that Oracle owns MySQL I guess it makes sense. That's super confusing though, that this pops up when searching for "oracle enum" on Google.

Comment: @h2ooooooo I agree, it's not very clear from the page, the only clear indication is the mysql prompt in a few examples a bit down the page. Been bitten by that myself before when looking for Oracle docs.

Comment: Yeah, the mysql prompt and the fact that the URL contains `5.5` (which you'd have to REALLY pay attention to), but they're not really the first things you check. They should simply add it in the URL, title, header, or even better; forward all the requests to mysql.com.

Comment: Thanks now , i got your query runs successfully and , i have one question , how to describe table.   desc table_name. . . is returning is not running properly.